# Is there an effective way to test if a RMI server is up?

Tags: java, rmi

I have a RMI client **testing if a RMI server is running and reachable**.

At the moment I perform every few seconds this test:

```
try {
    rMIinstance.ping();
} catch (RemoteException e) {
    getInstanceRegister().removeInstance(rMIinstance);
}
```

(`ping()` is a simple dummy RMI call.)

If the instance is offline the I get approx 1 minute later a

> `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out`

exception, showing me that the server is offline.

However the code **hangs one minute**, which is far to long for us. (I don't want to change the timeout setting.)
**Is there a method to perform this test faster?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could interrupt the thread from a timer. It's a bit hacky and will throw InterruptedException instead of RemoteException, but it should work.

```
try {
    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    TimerTask interruptTimerTask = new InterruptTimerTask(Thread.currentThread());
    timer.schedule(interruptTimerTask, howLongDoYouWantToWait);
    rMIinstance.ping();
    timer.cancel();
} catch (RemoteException | InterruptedException e) {
    getInstanceRegister().removeInstance(rMIinstance);
}
```

And the TimerTask implementation:

```
private static class InterruptTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    private Thread thread;

    public InterruptTimerTask(Thread thread) {
        this.thread=thread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        thread.interrupt();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the answer of @NeplatnyUdaj I found this solution:

```
try {
     ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
     Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Task(rMIinstance));
     System.out.println("Result: "+ future.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

} catch (RemoteException | TimeoutException e) {
     getInstanceRegister().removeInstance(rMIinstance);
}
```

And this task:

```
class Task implements Callable<String> {
        DatabaseAbstract rMIinstance;
        public Task(DatabaseAbstract rMIinstance)
        {
            this.rMIinstance = rMIinstance;
        }
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            rMIinstance.ping();
            return "OK";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a small tip: normally you would reuse the `ExecutorService`, as its purpose is to "cache" threads.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solutions that interrupt the thread making the RMI call might not work, depending on whether that thread is at a point where it can be interrupted. Ordinary in-progress RMI calls aren't interruptible.

Try setting the system property `java.rmi.server.disableHttp` to `true`. The long connection timeout may be occurring because RMI is failing over to its HTTP proxying mechanism. This mechanism is described -- albeit very briefly -- in the class documentation for [RMISocketFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/server/RMISocketFactory.html). (The HTTP proxying mechanism has been deprecated in JDK 8).

Comment: I tested `java.rmi.server.disableHttp` = `true`. It did not reduce the long connection timeout.

Comment: Oh well, it was worth a try. Sounds like you have a low-level connectivity problem when this happens then. Try ping first to see if the host is reachable and responding before trying RMI then.

Answer (score 0):

Set the system property [`sun.rmi.transport.proxy.connectTimeout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html) to the desired connect timeout in milliseconds. I would also set [`sun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html).

The answers suggesting interrupting the thread rely on platform-specific behaviour of `java.net`, whose behaviour when interrupted is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about interrupting. The problem with timeout is that other RMI instances on this VM should have a certain tolerance on timeout.

Comment: So use a longer timeout appropriate to the other remote methods and get rid of this one altogether. The other methods will throw exceptions if the timeout expires.